# primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: Could not load GPU driver after Intel driver installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I installed the latest Intel drivers today using this tool: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

I wanted to play Dota 2 with my nVidia graphics card.  I loaded up the game and it never loaded.  I removed the primusrun launch options and the game ran.

I went into console and typed: `primusrun glxgears` and I received this error message: `primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: Could not load GPU driver`.

This sent me on a wild goose chase reading askUbuntu articles, installing nVidia drivers that broke my system, removing all nVidia drivers, reinstall Bumblebee, etc.  Nothing works.  My computer at least boots back into Ubuntu now but I just want to play Dota 2 :(.

Are there any files that you nee to see to help diagnose the problem?  Thanks for your help!